# How can I change the Apache ErrorDocument from a Perl handler?

Tags: perl, apache, error-handling, handler

Is there a way to have your PerlAuthenHandler, PerlAuthzHandler, or even your PerlHandler change the error document for a request?

Example: When the user goes to a specific page and gets an error, I want to have a subroutine choose what error document errors are thrown to.

Answer (score 2):

I think [custom_response()](http://perl.apache.org/docs/2.0/api/Apache2/Response.html#C_custom_response_) may do what you want.

Comment: Hey Thanks, but I ended up sending a redirect command from the PerlAuthenHandler or PerlAuthzHandler

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible.
I will use a static ErrorDocument pointed at a perl program that will do the dynamic content